# How to prove this inequation in banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to $x_0$ in a Banach space, then prove that:$$ \underline{\lim}\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|x_n\|\geq\| x_0\| $$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This means $\forall f\in \mathscr{X}^{*}$,$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}<f,x_n>=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0)=<f,x_0>$$then,$$<x_0,f>\leq\underline{\lim}\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\parallel x_n\parallel\parallel f\parallel$$So we get the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Hahn Banach implies the existence of a linear form $f$ of norm $1$ such that $f(x_0)=\|x_0\|$. $\lim_nf(x_n)=f(x_0)=\|x_0\|$. Since $|f(x_n)|\leq \|f\|\|x_n\|=\|x_n\|$. We deduce that $\underline{\lim}_n\|x_n\|\geq \|x_0\|$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $\underline{\lim}\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ refers to the liminf, the limit inferior?

If this were not the case, there'd be a subsequence (also weakly convergent) where the norms converge outside the ball $B[0, \|x_0\|]$. But this contradicts the fact that this ball is weakly closed.

Comment: Yes，this means the limitinf.